# Understanding an integral from Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, integration

In Eberhard Zeidler's *Quantum Field Theory I: Basics in Mathematics and Physics,* under section 11.6.4 - Integration tricks, the following integral which is then evaluated using a Schwinger parameterization is given (see page 643):
$$J_D(p) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^D} \frac{d^D q}{q^2(p + q)^2}.$$
Here $p:= (p_0,p_1,\ldots, p_{D - 1})$, $p^2 = p_0^2 + p_1^2 + \cdots + p^2_{D-1}$, and $p, q \in \mathbb{R}^D$.

My question does not concern using a Schwinger parametrization to evaluate the integral. This I understand. Rather, my question concerns understanding the integral as it is actually written, with my lack of understanding stemming from my very limited knowledge of QFT.

Suppose $D = 3$. My guess is $p$ and $q$ are vector quantities of some sort. The integral as written appears to be in compact form. What I would like to know is how to rewrite the integral out explicitly as follows:
$$J_3(p) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{d^3 q}{q^2(p + q)^2} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty dq_1 dq_2 dq_3 (??).$$
I am sure this must be possible but have no idea exactly how this is to be done.

Comment: Probably, the square on $p$ and $q$ are implying scalar multiplication, so that $q^2 = q^\mu q_\mu$ and $(q+p)^2 = (q^\mu + p^\mu)(q_\mu + q_\mu)$.

Comment: That seems mostly fine though spherical coordinates are a better integration measure to use as it avoids all the problems you're encountering by using only the length and direction of $q_{\mu}$. Also most texts will start with $q_0$ as the temporal piece of q instead of $q_1$.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. You say $p^2 = p_0^2 + p_1^2 + \cdots$ so why can't you write the integrand as $1/(q_0^2 + q_1^2 + q_2^2)((p_0+q_0)^2 + (p_1+q_1)^2 + (p_2 + q_2)^2)$? Or are you asking how to write the integrand as $f_0(q_0) f_1(q_1) f_2(q_2)$? That's not possible in general.